# Climate change impact on the geography

Tags: climate-change, climate-models

Wildfires seem to be more frequent in the southern Europe, meantime as the Arctic melts, there are speculations that the Gulf Stream might collapse, would lower the temperature [10-15 degrees](https://www.bbc.com/news/science-environment-66289494) in Europe. At the same time the Arctic region is getting warmer. If we were to combine all of these trends, what kind of the environment do we expect in the future? Will the geographic location of "cold" and "warm" regions going to shift or will the available regions on Earth that have *normal* temperature amplitudes shrink?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tnVWUIhQ8dE just some inforrmation.

Comment: AFAIK, climate zones will drastically shift; most of them roughly polewards. See also https://e360.yale.edu/features/redrawing-the-map-how-the-worlds-climate-zones-are-shifting